# How to change the font of a ListView inside your java code?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a tabs as views in my activity. Each tab represents a `ListView`. To clarify things further, the `ListView`s don't have any `TextView`s inflated. Since there isn't a text attribute for a `ListView` in xml schema, I was wondering if I could do it inside my activity. If not then what would you suggest?

layout file: tabworkentry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Include action bar -->
<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/innerdashboard_bg"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- Top 10 starts -->

            <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Top_10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />

        <!-- Top 10 ends -->

        <!-- Billable starts -->
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/Billable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />

        <!-- Billable ends -->

        <!-- Product starts -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Product"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="this is a third tab" />

        <!-- Product ends -->

     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabworkentry);

TabHost  mTabHost = getTabHost();

 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("top10").setIndicator("Top  10").setContent(R.id.Top_10));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("billable").setIndicator("Billable").setContent(R.id.Billable));
     mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("product").setIndicator("Product").setContent(R.id.Product));

  mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Top_10);
  mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Top_10));   

  mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Billable);
  mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Billable));

 mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Product);
 mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Product));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e.getStackTrace());
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception" + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [Custom ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+custom+listview)

Comment: To learn more about [ListView and Custom adapter for ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to create own row layout and add TextView then you can set Text font...

Using custom layout you can do it...

so inflate   `R.layout.row`

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="15dp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: I'm aware of this approach. Thanks for letting me know that it's not possible though. May be I should just inflate a row then.

Answer (score 1):

In your approach you can't, it's not possible. But when you create your own class that extending for example from `BaseAdapter` then you can't change text look in `getView()` method but still you need to have `TextView`.

**Note:**

1. Simply create your own `row.xml` with contains `TextView`.
2. Use `BaseAdapter` and modify your font(color, size...) in `getView()` call.

Your `row.xml` can looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Note 2:** 

Also here you can set typeface but there is only three possible options (monospace, serif, sans).

Comment: Thanks! Inflating a new row with a new text view seems a lot easier.

Comment: np, this approach is also recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Billable){

@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

               convertView= super.getView();

                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);


                return convertView;
        }

}
```

Comment: what is text1? Is it a new layout file with a `TextView`?